# HTML, How to make repeatable header and footer when content reaches certain height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lets say that we have HTML template that has that kind of structure:

```
-------------
|Header Data|
-------------
|           |
| Main Data |
|           |
-------------
|Footer Data|
-------------
```

`Header Data`, `Main Data` and `Footer Data` have fixed height value.

However when `Main Data` starts to exceed its fixed height value, it should turn into something like this:

```
-------------
|Header Data|
-------------
|           |
| MainData1 |
|           |
-------------
|Footer Data|
-------------
-------------
|Header Data|
-------------
|           |
| MainData2 |
|           |
-------------
|Footer Data|
-------------
```

Is it possible to do that kind of thing only by using HTML and CSS?

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for but a simple way to solve the issue? `overflow-y`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y

Comment: Are you just asking about fixed position header/footers? Or do you actually want them to be duplicated and move with the page scroll?

Comment: @DBS I want them to be dublicated

Comment: Is this for a print layout?

Comment: @zgood Yes. I have been trying to use a lot of PDF generation libs, but requirements of my document are so specific that they don't cover all of these requirements

Comment: Would you like the content of `MainData1` to flow into `MainData2` once the content of `MainData1` exceeds the set height of `MainData1` and continue where it left of? Have you tried anything code wise?

Comment: The common solution for `@media screen` is to scroll the MainData between Header and Footer. The common solution for  `@media print` is to place everything in a `<table>` and place Header Data into a `<thead>` (`display: table-header-group;`) and Footer Data in `<tfoot>` (`display: table-footer-group;`). Printing the `<table>` will automatically add the header and the footer on every page.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu That was a great idea. I never had thought about it)) Could you write it as answer to my quetion with example so I could mark it as accepted? This could help pther people.

Comment: @Mr.D Does this [article](https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/the-ultimate-print-html-template-with-header-footer-568f415f6d2a) help? I think it does what you are asking. METHOD II is what Andrei mentioned, but the ULTIMATE METHOD looks the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `@media screen`, you should use a single `<header>` and `<footer>` and make the contents scrollable between the two.

For `@media print`, the obsolete solution (but it always worked) was to place everything in a `<table>` and use `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` elements with `display` values of `table-header-group` and `table-footer-group`, respectively.

The modern solution for `@media print`, however, is to use [running elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/#running-elements):

```css
header {
  position: running(header);
}

footer {
  position: running(footer);
}

@page {
  @top-center {
    content: element(header);
  }
  @bottom-center {
    content: element(footer);
  }
}
```

For details on how to use the `@page` model, please refer to the [official documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/#page-model). Also note its current browser support is slightly [below 80%](https://caniuse.com/#search=%40page), globally.